# Filebeat: how to pass file properties to Logstash?

Tags: logstash, kibana, filebeat

How can I read a file property (file.log) which holds a key value, for example:
[image: user.comment value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AHDB.png)

I want to pass the "user.comment" value to Logstash via Filebeat and to show it inside Kibana.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your Logstash configuration you can use the **`kv`** filter plugin, it uses some options to help you parse messages from your log file.

Example:

```
#/etc/logstash/conf.d/filter.conf

filter { 
   kv { 
     value_split => "=" 
   } 
}
```

**Note:** by default, the kv plugin performs the parsing action on the `message`, and the default delimiterfor identifying key-value relations is `=`

Comment: Alright, maybe I need to explain my self-deeper:

I have many devices around the world who needs to send their logs data (which means log file with metadata) to Filebeat and it sends it to Logstash -> ElasticSearch -> Kibana.
The log files have some Metadata (as you've seen in the picture attached).

My goal is to get the metadata from the log files and send it to Logstash.

Comment: If you ask why should I need this ability?
Let's say that I receive a log file with 30,000 rows and I want to add an additional data to the log files without adding it into each row in the file (for example a device ID). It's not efficient to add the device ID into each row, so the proper solution is to add it to the file metadata.

I'm sure that Filebeat has the ability to read a file metadata and send it to Logstash, it should be called file enrichment.

Comment: I'm not sure you can send metadata only once, even the name of the log file from which Filebeat is listening to is always sent with every event.